# How do you get data out of JBPM/Drools process instance?

Tags: java, drools, jbpm

So we're exploring using Drools/JBPM, and we're finding it very difficult to get data out of JBPM. I feel like we're missing something obvious.

We're kicking a JBPM process off using the RESTful interface and creating a process instance: POST `/server/containers/{containerId}/processes/{processId}/instances`

After the process instance is complete however, we need to retrieve the results. How do you do that? Is there something in the JBPM process we need to set (like a variable or what not)?

We've poured through a ton of examples and docs at this point and can't seem to find an answer to what should be simple.

Thank you,
-Jonathan

Comment: Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433776/jbpm-how-to-get-workitemhandler-results

Comment: Not exactly. We understand we have to store stuff in variables. We can't seem to figure out what rest call to retrieve that with

Comment: Hello Jonathan, are you storing the data in process variables?

Comment: Also, what Kie Server version are you using?

Comment: 7.23. Yes, we're storing a Request object and a Response object as variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make a `POST` request to `/server/containers/{containerId}/processes/{processId}/instances` it will return your process instance id.

***Get results from current running process:*** 
`GET /server/containers/{containerId}/processes/definitions/{processId}/variables`

***Get results from past running processes:***
`GET /server/queries/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/variables/instances/{varName}`

Go to "process instances" in workbench to make sure you are storing data

[image: Kie Workbench]

Comment: Thanks!!! Is there a way to have return the process variables instead of having to retrive them after termination? (Syncronous invocation instead of async?)

Comment: Are you using this variable for another process?

Comment: Quite possibly, we might call out, then need to call another ruleset. For now, we're just trying to view the data!

Comment: If you want to use it for another process, you would need to create and initialize a global variable. If you are asking to view the data.. you can use workbench in order to do so. Because you are "creating" a process instance, it is (correctly) returning the new id of the instance created when you initialize a process.

Comment: Also updated answer. You will probably want to use the 2nd endpoint... you will need to provide the process instance id... The first endpoint will get the results of any process variables of any currently running processes.